# Graduation rates

Tags: ethics

And so, at the faculty senate meeting (at a large public university) an administrator is gloating how the graduation rates have soared by anywhere from 5 to 50% (at different colleges of the university) within a short span of a few years (1-3). This came after the administration made very strong pronouncements that "we must increase graduation rates..." I sarcastically suggested we patent the method of getting such a great surge in success rate. All other faculty were silent and it appears to me that this is a national trend. Nobody seems to care about quality.

Surely, to have these graduation rates surge, some variables need to change. None of them did -- same poorly prepared students, same faculty and no revolutionary education discoveries. Conclusion -- good old grade inflation and social promotion is the cause, but here prompted by a snap of fingers of the corporate executives and executed gladly by compliant faculty. Am I missing something?

Questions: How is it that faculty (and tenured faculty at that) seem to not give a hoot about the quality of education, rather seem to be perfectly content with this corporate drive to convert universities into blatant diploma mills? Why are students willing to pay for a piece of paper that has no backing?

Any serious explanations?

Comment: It would be great to hear from people who dislike my questions.

Comment: I can't see a real question in there, it's just a rant. Unless your question is "why do less-good universities still get students"?

Comment: @scaahu  Hope it is better now?

Comment: @nengel  Is a special paragraph titled "questions" enough to point to questions?

Comment: No. I can read, that was not the issue. The problem is that those "questions" presuppose a large part of the answer (e.g. that faculty do not care about quality of education), so there is no way to answer them other than "yes, your anger is valid".

Comment: @nengel  It would be great to hear from people who contradict my assumptions. That would be one way to answer it. p.s. I do not get mad, I get even.

Comment: LOW graduation rate, Low interest to study there. Low income-

Comment: -1: Your story is hard to follow due to unusual grammatical structures and excessive parentheticals. You’ll be much more comprehensible if you write in a straightforward manner. Your questions also seem like a complete non-sequitur from the preceding story.

Comment: Ay my institution, administration lowered standards, the faculty union filed a lawsuit, and that court case was lost. Nowadays, administration has legal carte blanche to do whatever they want. Faculty can't stay enraged forever for nothing. See Ginsburg, *The Fall of the Faculty*: https://www.insidehighered.com/news/2011/07/14/new_book_argues_bloated_administration_is_what_ails_higher_education

Comment: When the Dean of the engineering school retired at the Uni I was at - he was clearing out his filing cabinets and came across a final exam from 30 years ago - when it was looked at they realised that the current final year students would not be able to solve the questions : too long and too challenging - but, they say standards have not changed...

Comment: An improvement in graduation rates in a short time could be accomplished by better identification of students who have met credit requirements or are missing a class or two and helping them finish up.

Comment: I am not clear that this is grade inflation. A lot of my students' matriculation is driven by finances. Perhaps they are better able to finance their education in the current economy climate and are therefore completing more rapidly.

Answer (score 6):

It's difficult for individuals to resist societal trends.

The grade inflation is in no way driven only by colleges seeking to make a quick buck - they are responding to a higher demand for graduates. The "knowledge economy" plays a role in this, but also *employer* degree inflation - it seems like many companies these days will only hire people with a university degree for jobs that were in the past done by high school graduates. In essence, these days, in terms of getting a job, a college degree is the new high school diploma. (Which answers your question of why students pay for them.)

That means that you now have not only the top few students of a year, but a much larger group to educate. The average high schooler probably didn't get massively smarter though (but probably has to work more hours on the side than in the past to pay to be there), so you necessarily have to lower your standards a bit. That doesn't mean that the degree becomes 'useless': they will still learn things in these four years, just not quite as many as a class made only of valedictorians would.

That's for the societal trend that drives these developments. Individual faculty see their individual students, having taken on large debt, struggling to get somewhere. Now, they can give them a failing grade, or not.

They probably feel compassion for their students. They are surely aware of the general trends, and realize that the neighboring universities one or two places up or down the rankings are giving similar students a pass. Why would they want to punish these students in front of them in particular, that they have grown to know and like, and condemn them to a life of burger-flipping, when they are no less deserving than their peers?

They also probably think their university (and their research, which has its own inflationary pressures forcing them to concentrate less on their teaching) has value, and don't want to see it close due to lack of funds because no students want to risk studying there any more. If the faculty don't act as a cohesive group (insert herding cats joke), an individual faculty member faces additional pressure because they are suddenly giving worse average grades to the same students than their fellow teachers,  which leads to awkward questions from students and the administration. Faculty are as susceptible to peer pressure as anyone, and somewhat likely to think that maybe they are doing something wrong in that situation, not everyone else.

Comment: +1 I feel sad but I think what you say is quite true.

Comment: +1 so sad but so true. I wish that you had references also.

Comment: @SSimon: hah, me too. I have no idea how accurate this is - I'm in CS, I don't have the social science background to even know how to evaluate that - it just *feels like* it's true.

Comment: @nengel, thank you for an attempt at answering this rather complex question. I am a tad surprised that a few of you want to kill it. I think it is a question of fundamental importance. Surely universities are taking on more and more students which (many colleagues) know will not make it, even after reduction of standards. To my query, an administrator replied that "students have a right to fail". What about patient having a right to die, even though you know a way (however hard) to save them. Do we have ethical obligations to the society.

Comment: @nengel Would one be happy to be operated on by a physician who had gotten their diploma with reduced or non-existent standards? In this respect, do universities of today differ in quality from internet diploma mills from a decade ago? Surely, we can pretend that these are issues one cannot discuss, yet if we do not, things will become even worse than they are now. In my research, only 30% of random US population (school to PhD diplomas) can add 1/2+1/3. Is that something to brush off and wink away?

Comment: @Rado: That's ironic, just yesterday I was reading about how medical entrance exams are getting harder and harder. Because there are more applicants, the top universities, and the most highly attractive fields, actually have an even better top bracket. This answer is all about average unis and average-interest fields. Harvard doesn't have a problem getting a class of valedictorians!

Comment: @Nengel the example University I used has its share of Nobel prize winners among its faculty in a number of fields; it is a huge public university. Yes, I hear this "argument" that "because our top achievers are so good, we cannot be that bad..."  Then you look at the winners of math Olympiads and realize that a) A number of them are increasingly home schooled, and b) almost all of them are first generation Americans -- their parents coming from "former Soviet Union", China, India, and all.  More than half of Mathematics PhD's are foreign educated, and not coming from our public schools/univer

Comment: @ In other words, tiny size places like Harvard are getting their feed not from educational institutions that are supported by public money. Thus the question arises as to whether such huge expenditure on our education is justified, if all it does is churns the diplomas. I am horrified by the fact that these kinds of discussions are a taboo in our society, not unlike an incestuous or abusive family where the abuses are a ferboten topic. It is similar in education ("research") publications that seem only concerned about feeling good, and self-praises. You have hinted a bit at the causes.

Comment: @Rado: it hasn't been my experience at all that "these discussions are taboo". I didn't come up with this answer based on personal observations from three semesters of grading after all. Maybe you are talking to very different people, or maybe (as happened in this question) you are going into these discussions with such an aggressive attitude that people don't want to engage with you?

Comment: @Nengel, after 30+ years of teaching at (mostly) top universities across three continents and about 1/3 of my research publications in education, you would think I know what I am talking about. I have heard of these deep conversations about the taboo topics but I do not remember ever hearing them at faculty or similar meetings. And that is 30+ years we are talking about. But since you have different experiences, kindly direct me to the place where these free and deep conversations about quality of our education are happening. I clearly need to frequent such places. I would definitely appreciat

Comment: @Nengel Do not take me wrong, I appreciate your input, even though I may not find it completely honest -- at least you are engaging. The others chickened out and shut the conversation down with various excuses. I have an ongoing monograph with a reputable publisher and one of the chapters is on what I term "commercial education". As for my "aggression", I wish it were true;  these matters require aggressive approach. Else, your characterization of "aggressive" confirms my claim of taboo. I am sure the Queen would consider an attempt to shake hands with her an aggression/status quo challenge.

Comment: @Rado: I don't know what the queen (which one?) has to do with anything, but I'm sure it would help not to go into conversations implying that the other person is uncaring and venal and ethically lacking. Principle of charity? Humanity? One of these. When your first move is to attack, of course you will only get defensive reactions.

Comment: As for the where, I've discussed the topic/seen it discussed both in individual conversation and social media. I'd think for an exploratory conversation (since you profess to seek understanding) you'd have more luck over drinks at a conference social event than at a faculty meeting.

Comment: @nengel, sorry if you felt I was "attacking" you. I of course have nothing against you, since you are only a string of 0 and 1's to me. But nonetheless we at least had some conversation about the topic that has been bugging me. We did not get anything on the account of ETHICS which is my main issue, but life is not perfect.

Comment: @Rado: I'm not actually faculty, I'm still a PhD student, so I didn't feel you were attacking me personally, just that you were being tremendously unfair to people like my advisor who I've generally found to be good, honest people doing their best. As for ethics, unless you literally work for a university that would give your cat a degree if it paid the tuition, I don't think that deciding to go down in degree quality a little is actually immoral. There's nothing inherently unethical about being a not-so-good university - they can't all be at the top.

Comment: @Rado: of course, there are fields where it's more of an issue than others (medicine, civil engineering, maybe law?). But in these jobs where lives literally depend on how good you are, I don't think they just let the fresh graduates loose to do their worst. And what's worse, a poor nurse or no nurse at all? It's far from being the kind of clear-cut situation where a "what is WRONG with you" attitude is warranted.

Comment: @nengel I did not think you were faculty nor that most of the stack exchange people are. The reactions of faculty and non faculty to these kinds of inquiries are often recognizably distinct. I am afraid that I disagree with you on the point of little slips of quality and then OK for some fields, not so OK for others. Standards and quality are RIGID categories, otherwise they do not exist.

Comment: @nengel As for the honesty of faculty, sure I have not heard a single faculty member (and throughout my career I have known no less than a thousand) that would not claim to be the greatest educator and the most ethical educator. Yet, we have a population that is exceedingly illiterate and innumerate, with or without diplomas. Who educated them? A faculty who has tenure must have been either a) at a university that does not pay attention to teaching or b) he must have engaged in wholesale social promotion of students. I knew no exceptions to these two possibilities.

Comment: @nengel Big part of the problem is that there is no QUALITY control in education. Nobody checks whether students acquired any knowledge throughout their schooling and, most importantly, whether they acquired the most important ability, namely ability to think. For high school students it is clear to everyone that (barring a handful of schools) this is the most wasteful expenditure of taxpayer money one can think of. Twelve years of schooling and, for the most part nothing to show for it. Very similar situation is with pre PhD "education"... GRE, oh man, major problem! Hell, why???

Comment: "Ability to think" is untestable. For the rest, as someone who did high school & undergraduate in France, where there are nationwide standards & exams set by the government and yet the problems are exactly the same, I can only say you are very wrong about that. Also, source on illiteracy rates going up??